# Кнопка в LinerLayout, который внутри FrameLayout не нажимается

Tags: android, xml, android-button

Здравствуйте. У меня есть разметка, в которой находятся `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout` и ещё один `LinearLayout`:

```
LinearLayout
|   ....
|   FrameLayout
|   |   ...
|   |   LinearLayout
|   |   |    Button
```

Повесил на кнопку лисенер, запускаю -- кнопка на нажатие не реагирует. Убрал кнопку их `LinearLayout` -- всё заработало:

```
LinearLayout
|   ....
|   FrameLayout
|   |   Button
|   |   LinearLayout
|   |   |
```

Сама разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etNewChat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_new_chat_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btNewChat"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_new_chat_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contactsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Что нужно сделать, что бы кнопка нажималась и внутри `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементы в `FrameLayout` выводятся по порядку следования в xml. То есть ваш `ListView` перекрывает собой кнопку. Чтобы кнопка была поверх списка, поменяйте `ListView` и `LinearLayout` местами.

Есть бесплатные курсы на [udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud862), там как раз рассказывается в частности о разных layout'ах, тонкостях и возможностях. Даже если многое известно, полезно пролистать.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю попробовать вместо `FrameLayout` использовать `RelativeLayout`, потому что в вашем случае, судя по всему, список налезает на кнопку и тем самым кнопку перекрывает

Comment: Смысл использование `FrameLayout` в том, что бы кнопка была над списком, а не возле него.

Comment: @Evgeniy элементы в FrameLayout выводятся по порядку следования в xml. Т.е. ваш ListView перекрывает собой кнопку. Чтобы кнопка была поверх списка, поменяйте ListView и LinearLayout местами.

Comment: @YuraIvanov оформите как ответ, плюсану.